# Trying to add divs before and after $.each item while including the result itself

Tags: jquery, append, each, prepend

My JS is

```
b = "form#recipeSearch";
c = $(b).attr('action') + '?r';
f = "#searchResults";

var opentemplate = '<div class="row">';
var closetemplate = '</div>';

perPageLimit = response.max;
totalResults = response.total;

o = 0; // global counter

$.each(response.items, function(i,item) {

    var template = '                <div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg" id="' + item.uid + '">'
                 + '                    <div class="recipe-info">'
                 + '                        ' + item.nutritional.calories + ' CAL'
                 + '                        ' + item.rating 
                 + '                    </div>'
                 + '                    <a href="' + item.link + '" rel="popover" title="' + item.title + '" data-content="' + item.description + '"><img src="' + item.image + '" alt="' + item.title + '"></a>'
                 + '                </div>';      


    if(o == 0){ // if start of rows display open template
        $(f).append(opentemplate); 
    }        

    $(f).append(template); // inject template

    if(o == 4){ // if end of rows close template
        $(f).append(closetemplate); 
        o = 0; // reset global counter
    }  

    if(o == item.length - 1){ // if last item close the div
        $(f).append(opentemplate);
    }

    o++; //plus global counter
});
```

It's currently displaying as:

```
<div class="row"></div> <!-- ONLY ONCE :( -->
<div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg"></div>
<div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg"></div>
<div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg"></div>
<div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg"></div>
<div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg"></div>
<div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg"></div>
<div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg"></div>
```

and so on...

**Where I am looking for it to be**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg"></div>
    <div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg"></div>
    <div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg"></div>
    <div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg"></div>
</div>
```

**and then so on each 4 items until it hits the end and then put < / d i v >**

Now i'm trying to get the code to if i = 0 then display the opening of the row tag, then after 4 items, close the div, and that continues until they get the end result and if it's the end to display the closing div.

Any suggestions, I've been at this for a bit now..

Comment: where is the o increasing? A fiddle could be helpful

Comment: Where is o incremented? And what is f?

Comment: I've updated the code. @PulkitMittal a fiddle is not a viable option right now.

Comment: Why do you want to insert openTemplate again if it's the last item? Shouldn't that be closeTemplate?

Comment: I only want to insert openTemplate before every four items, after all four are inserted, I'm inserting closeTemplate and then resetting the counter to 0 and starting the check over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/KwNFN/4/

Before the `.each()` I created an output string, and I dont `append` it until the string is complete. This should also be slightly better for performance, as you are not (incorrectly) updating your DOM after every single element.

You also don't need a global counter, `i` should suffice.

The final code will look something like this:

```
output = "";

$.each(response.items, function(i,item) {
    var template = '<div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg" id="item.uid">'
                 + '  <div class="recipe-info">'
                 + '  your template goes here'
                 + '  </div>'
                 + '</div>';

    if(i%4 == 0){ // if start of rows display open template
       template = opentemplate + template;
    }
    // if end of row, or if last item, close the div
    else if(i%4 == 3 || i == response.items.length-1 ){ 
        template = template + closetemplate;
    }  

    output = output + template; // update template
});

$(f).append(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem to me here:

```
if(o == item.length - 1){ // if last item close the div
        $(f).append(opentemplate);
}
```

o should be compared to response.items.length and not to item.length.

Tell me if I'm wrong?

Comment: That doesn't resolve the main issue, i need to cover each result with <div class="row"> <!-- 4 results here --> </div> and then continue with that pattern until there is the last result and then close it with just </div> - Currently it only ouputs <div class="row"></div> and then displays out all the results below it.

Answer (score 0):

```
o = 0; // global counter
```

Why you need it?

```
function(i,item)
```

`i` - index of item in collection `response.items`
and `item` is current item

```
$(f).append(opentemplate); 
$(f).append(closetemplate);
```

This code update DOM, you can't insert `<div class="row">` and then after few iterations add `</div>`

**Added:**

```
var template;
$.each(response.items, function(index, item)
{
    if(index%4 == 0)
    {
        template = '<div class="row">';
    }

    template += '<div class="col3 boxee wrappedImg">...</div>';      

    if(index == response.items.length - 1 || index%4 == 3){
        $(f).append(template + '</div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Well then how do you suggest I do so?